# Three ODE conundrum...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a 1st order ODE:

$$y'(t)=f(y)=a(b-y)\tag{1}$$

which has an exact solution;

$$\int \mathrm{d}y\frac{1}{f(y)}=t$$

And a second 1st order ODE:

$$y'(t)=g(y)=c[d^4-y^4]\tag{2}$$

which has an exact solution;

$$\int \mathrm{d}y\frac{1}{g(y)}=t$$

And a third 1st order ODE:

$$y'(t)=f(y)+g(y)\tag{3}$$

with inital condition $(0,y_0)$, **but which has no exact solution, because;**

$$\int  \mathrm{d}y\frac{1}{f(y)+g(y)}$$

can't be integrated.

Although $(3)$ does seem very suited to numerical methods, I wonder because $(1)$ and $(2)$ have exact solutions whether there's some trick or theorem that could use that information to help solve $(3)$?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: To quote [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.`  Please be more specific.

Comment: @user539887: Hi. I've made the functions explicit. Hope this helps.